# mongodb - Is it possible to group with the $bucket operator by date?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

is it possible to group by date with the mongodb $bucekt operator ?

```
       {
        $bucket: {
          groupBy: // date field? 
          boundaries: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50, 75, 100, 500],
          default: 'overBucket',
          output: {
            count: {
              $sum: 1,
            },
            localities: {
              $push: '$$ROOT',
            },
          },
        },
      },
```

Thanks in advance for the suggestions :)

Comment: Yes, of course, it will work. I am personally using a code in Production where a `$bucket` pipeline is grouped by `date` without `time` suffixes

Comment: hello @hhharsha36 can you give me an example? I tried to group by date  but i become every time the same result.

Comment: Please provide sample documents to work on

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/emReFARwxEX

Comment: i tried to create the same situation. I hope it is understand-fully

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think the below code is what you are looking for:

```
db.events.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "type": {
        "$in": [
          "EVENT",
          "SUBEVENT"
        ]
      },
      "verification.status": "APPROVED",
      "verification.public": true,
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "$dateToString": {
          "date": "$baseData.startDate",
          "format": "%Y-%m-%d"
        },
        
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1,
        
      },
      events: {
        $push: "$$ROOT",
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

Let me know if you are trying to achieve `$bucket` stage with days as boundaries

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PoSueVIiPjn)